# Python: secondary window is not destroying completely

Tags: python, tkinter

There's a Tkinter project I'm doing for understanding both python and tkinter.
I'm stuck at a situation where I call secondary popup window from main window and after the popup is being destroyed its not returning to main screen.

File mainScr.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import popup

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width*0.8, height*0.8, width*0.1, height*0.1))

def popup():
    showPopup()
    print("popup destroyed")

show_btn = tk.Button(root, command= popup) 
show_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

File popup.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class showPopup():
    def __init__(self):
        self.popup = tk.Toplevel()
        self.popup.title("Details")
        w = 400     # popup window width
        h = 250     # popup window height
        sw = self.popup.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.popup.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.popup.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.show()
        self.popup.mainloop()

    def save(self):        
        self.popup.destroy()

    def show(self):
        save_btn = tk.Button(self.popup, text="Save", command= self.save)
        save_btn.pack()
```

Above is the code of mine, I've called `showPopup()` class from main screen which creates new popup window using `Toplevel()` in tkinter.
But even if I destroyed the popup window, it should return to main window and print "popup destroyed" but it isn't.

The popup is closing but print statement is not executed. And when I close main window, console then execute the print statement

Comment: In your popup.py script,  the show() function needs to have self as a parameter because it is in the showPopup class

Comment: Also, when I 'import popup.py', I get an error which goes away when I 'import popup' instead

Comment: @JamesHuang Thank you for the suggestions, but there's a typo while writing here but yeah show() already have self parameter and I've imported  as 'import popup'.  sorry

Comment: You should not call `mainloop()` more than once.  Remove `self.popup.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some messing around, I have found the solution.

(This is after you have made previous changes regarding my earlier comments which contained code that I later changed to fix this).

It appears that the main error comes from you declaring an object of class `showPopup()` in the `popup()` function.

The first fix I had to make was that showPopup was from another file. To fix this, I wrote `popup.showPopup()` However, this is not right because the code thinks it's a function.

To fix the problem above, I had to import popup in another way. since you are only using the showPopup class, simply do `from popup import showPopup`. Now get rid of the `popup.showPopup()` if you put that down already because that doesn't work.

Now, you just have to call save() on the class. To do this, I assigned your showPopup() class to a variable called `new` and then called `new.save()` under it.

I also removed popup.mainloop() because it isn't needed for TopLevel()'s

Full Code:

mainScr.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from popup import showPopup

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width * 0.8, height * 0.8, width * 0.1, height * 0.1))


def popup():
    new = showPopup()
    new.save()
    print("popup destroyed")


show_btn = tk.Button(root, command=popup)
show_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

popup.py:

```
import tkinter as tk


class showPopup():
    def __init__(self):
        self.popup = tk.Toplevel()
        self.popup.title("Details")
        w = 400  # popup window width
        h = 250  # popup window height
        sw = self.popup.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.popup.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w) / 2
        y = (sh - h) / 2
        self.popup.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    def save(self):
        self.popup.destroy()

    def show(self):
        save_btn = tk.Button(self.popup, text="Save", command=self.save)
        save_btn.pack()
```

Comment: `new.save()` will destroy the just created toplevel.

Comment: Tried, but now on popup window button is not displaying. popup is just a blank screen

Comment: @JamesHuang thanks, this is working good as I removed 'popup.mainloop()' from popup.py, but I want to execute print statement after the popup is destroyed

Comment: I thought the code does that. As ac1668 has described, the code in the popup() function destroys the newly created toplevel and prints that it has. I don't see what the error here is.

Comment: @MayankJain You can add `self.popup.wait_window()` at the end of `__init__()` function of `showPopup` class (i.e. replace `self.popup.mainloop()`).

Comment: @acw1668 yes, I already tried and it worked. Thanks